# UserControl, Child Master Page and Parent Master Page (How to call function form User Control)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Basically I have a userControl.ascx with a lot of code... this user control is used in the Child.MasterPage and the Child.MasterPage inherits from a Parent.MasterPage.

In the Parent.MasterPage I have a method in the .cs file, this method accepts a string and passes it to a literal.

The problem:

I have spent hours trying to pass a string from my UserControl directly to the Parent.MasterPage.cs method with no luck. The child.MasterPage does not have a c# file, it just inherits from the parent.master

a line of code that I am using so that I can pass values to the patent.MasterPage reads like this.. but I am not able to pass to the method please help!

```
MasterPage myMasterPage = this.Parent.Parent.Page.Master.Master;.
```

Comment: of course if you ever want to modify your UI you're probably having to go and change this line everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typecasting it like ((ParentMaster)this.parent.parent).SomeMethod()