# UserControl pass Value to MasterPage Content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am coding in a userControl,

how can I pass text to a  control I placed in one of the contents?

It's a literal by the way

Thank you

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514620/usercontrol-child-master-page-and-parent-master-page-how-to-call-function-form

Comment: Nah that other one was how to pass to a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a public property in Master page.

```
public string WhateverPropertyName
{
    get
    {
        return LiteralControlInMasterPage.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        LiteralControlInMasterPage.Text = value;
    }
}
```

and then access it from the usercontrol as

```
Page.Master.WhateverPropertyName = "Whatever new value";
```

If you cannot access/update master page use

```
Literal mpLiteral = (Literal) Master.FindControl("masterPageLiteralControlID");
```

Comment: I actually wanted in the body so i want to put it in the content.

Comment: This is only an example to how to access the controls in master page. You can do anything you want.

Comment: What if I can only access it through the UserControl and dont have access to the MasterPage.cs?

Comment: I added the literal in the <asp:content><asp:Literal ID="myLiteral"></Literal>, it would automatically put it there? , I am sorry i am kind of new with c#

Comment: asp:content would be in the page not in the master page. Do you want to access the Literal control that is in Master page or in the Page?

Comment: They have it so weird here.. basically they have parent.master where the ContentTemplates are.. and then they have the Contents in the child.master... And I am coding from a UserControl

Comment: It is giving me a nullReferenceException gooleTrackin = track.GetTrack(track.OrderType.YAHOO); Literal mpLiteral = (Literal)this.Parent.Page.Master.FindControl("litGoogleADS"); mpLiteral.Text = gooleTrackin.ToString(); //nullReference here